# Update query fails almost 1 in 10 times

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this query:

```
$wd=1.5480;
$query = "UPDATE books SET myprice= myprice + $wd";
```

The query fails almost 1 in 10 times. There is no obvious pattern I can spot.
The column I try to update is a float. The value varies from 0 to 9.99999.
 
I've set the error log to report **the error in the query, and display the query itself**.
I've got this error in error log:

```
Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=+1' 
at line 1<br/><br/>
Query:UPDATE books SET =+1
```

As you can see the myprice is missing from the query.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that `myprice` isn't a variable?

Comment: Try enclosing `myprice` in backticks.

Comment: @ExplosionPills There's no dollar sign before `myprice`.

Comment: Some more of the code would probably help here.  MySQL doesn't just up and delete column names.  There's something funky about the code that's actually issuing this query to the server.

Comment: I replicate the error using this code @cHao

Comment: Not *just* that code; you're not sending a query that i can see.  The problem is somewhere between the `$query =` and the actual call that sends the query to the DB.  It'd help to see that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$query = "UPDATE books SET `myprice` = `myprice`+".$wd;
```

Comment: `myprice` is not a reserved word.  Even if it were, it wouldn't be removed from the query; MySQL would just complain about an unexpected keyword or something.

Comment: @cHao I have not removed it I am telling into query that it is a field name and adding the value of it will the php variable value.

Comment: MySQL would already know it was a field name, cause that's what goes in that spot in SQL.  The problem is, it never even *sees* `myprice` (as evidenced by the error, which shows it's been totally stripped out).  Somewhere between the `$query = ` and the actual execution, the SQL is getting mangled.

Comment: @MIsspoo, thanks. I've executed 2000 queries with success!

Comment: @Kabamaru: If this actually fixed your problem, there's something you're not telling us.  A straight `mysqli_query` or `$db->prepare($query)` wouldn't mangle the SQL the way you're describing.  Ever.  Period.  How are you running the query?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `books` SET `myprice` = `myprice` + $wd";
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `books` SET `myprice` = `myprice` + $wd";
```

Comment: Good, though backticks aren't neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $wd=1.5480;

  $query = "UPDATE books SET `myprice` = `myprice` + {$wd}";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace " by ' to avoid unwanted var interpretation, and use sprintf() for query construction :

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE books SET myprice = myprice + %s', $wd);
```

Comment: Why down vote ?
Backsticks are for reserved keywords, and "myprice" is not ...

Comment: I agree; this doesn't *quite* deserve a downvote.  Backticks are not necessary here.  Something's reinterpreting the query, and this at least eliminates one of the possible points of breakage.  Though i'd change the `%s` to a `%f` or something, as it should never be a non-float...

Comment: Well, technically, it *should* be a non-float, cause floats suck when you're dealing with money.  SQLwise, it should probably be a `decimal`.  But til that's fixed, `%f` at least eliminates the chance of syntax errors and SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

you missed $ infront of myprice variable that might be the reason

Comment: He didn't miss the $ because he wants to add a value to the existing value of the current field name,
(myprice <-- column name = myprice <-- column name + $wd)